# Display users First and last name in plain text from the database and not in array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have a html page that sends value `phone` to log.php:

```
<?php 
    $PHONE = $_POST['phone'];

    mysql_connect('host.com', 'user', 'pass'); mysql_select_db('userdb');  

    $results = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PHONE='$PHONE'",
                             mysql_real_escape_string($PHONE))) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    { 
        $rows[1] = $row; 
    }
    print_r($rows)
?>
```

I get the result in log.php file in the form of an array from the database-

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [FNAME] => Vikrant [LNAME] => Kelkar ) )
```

I have table 'details' created

> FNAME-First name
>
> LNAME-Lastname
>
> BIRTHDAY-Birthday
>
> PHONE- user's no.

My Question is , I want to just display ' Vikrant Kelkar ' as a result in log.php file , and not the whole array but just the First & Last Name of user. Any help would be greatfull ?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(FNAME, ' ', LNAME) AS FULLNAME FROM details;

Comment: Do things in PHP over MySQL. It's faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply access the array:

```
echo $rows[0]["FNAME"] . " " . $rows[0]["LNAME"];
```

Comment: In echo ['here'] , should I write [1] or [0] before both LNAME & FNAME

Comment: Since you've assigned `$row` to `$rows[1]`, you should use `1` and not `0` as such: `echo $rows[1]["FNAME"] . $rows[1]["LNAME"];`

Comment: Should I erase the code print_r($rows) & insert this in its place echo $rows[1]["FNAME"] . $rows[1]["LNAME"];

Comment: It is showing VikrantKelkar in result using, echo $rows[1]["FNAME"] . $rows[1]["LNAME"]; I want a space in between like this Vikrant Kelkar

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to make it into an array unless you have more than one result.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
        { 
        $full_name = $row['FNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME']; 
        //$full_name[] = $row['FNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME']; // multi result
        }
        
echo $full_name;
//echo $full_name[0]; // loop thro foreach
```

think about learning pdo/mysqli as the mysql library will not function in php soon.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using while loop. SQL WHERE clause condition is phone number so it will be unique and return only one row.therefore,just remove while loop and do simply the following.

```
<?php 
$PHONE = $_POST['phone'];

mysql_connect('host.com', 'user', 'pass'); mysql_select_db('userdb');  

$results = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PHONE='$PHONE'",mysql_real_escape_string($PHONE))) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
echo $row['FNAME']." ".$row['LNAME'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can MySQL's [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to build the full name when querying the database. For example:-

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('host.com', 'user', 'pass'); mysql_select_db('userdb');  

$results = mysql_query(sprintf(
    "SELECT CONCAT(FNAME, ' ', LNAME) AS NAME FROM `details` WHERE PHONE='%s';",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'])
));

$rows = array();

if($results)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    { 
        $rows[] = $row; 
    }
}

print_r($rows)
?>
```

Anthony.